# CSS background-image alignment issue

Tags: html, css, image, background

My background image won't align between the divs in this code - I have tried clearing them to no avail. Anyone know what's causing it, or how I can get it to work? CSS in html for convenience.

```
<div class="header" style="height:200px; background-image: url(bg.png); margin:-8px;">
<img src="logo.png" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" />
</div>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="background-image: url(bg.png);background-position:center;  
display:inline-block; width:90px; border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;">Div 1</div>
    <div style="background-image: url(bg.png);background-position:center;  
display:inline-block; width:400px;margin:-4px;">Div 2</div>
    <div style="background-image: url(bg.png);background-position:center;  
display:inline-block; width:90px;border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FphKk/

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZzj9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your margins are shifting the divs and therefore their backgrounds causing the stripe misalignment:

No margins: [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/FphKk/3/)

Added back the inline-block and removed margins in addition to creating a container div with a set width - otherwise the stripes misalign based on window width.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/FphKk/4/)

Comment: Although how would I then align all of this to the centre of the page? And how can I make the header div span the entire page (100%)? Sorry I'm finding this very fiddly, whatever I change breaks something else.

Comment: The overall design is very "hinky". You'd do better with a single background image and round the two bottom corners. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/FphKk/6/ but without knowing why you initially created things the way you did, I was adjusting your code, not reconfiguring it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any background images, but as far as I can tell, the 2nd `<div>` wouldn't align between the 1st and 3rd `<div>`, because you used `display:inline-block;` instead of `display:inline;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/bcnobel/FphKk/1/

I honestly can't tell what this does to your background image's position, because you didn't set the full url to the image.
I will look into that as soon as you change the url's.

Comment: Ok, so I added in the background images and separated the html and css (only because I think it's more clear that way). Also, is there a full url to `logo.png`? 

Is this what you wanted? 
http://jsfiddle.net/bcnobel/FphKk/2/

Comment: No unfortunately. Do you see the stripes of the background are still misaligned on the div 1, 2 and 3? I need to align them somehow.